# Magento custom category attribute not saving

Tags: php, magento, categories, magento-1.9

https://www.ashsmith.io/2013/03/quick-tip-adding-custom-category-attributes-to-magento/
Using this link I've set up my custom category attribute, it does show up in the backend but it will not save so that I can retrieve and show the value in the frontend.

var dump shows this:

```
object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category)[19]
protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'catalog_category' (length=16)
protected '_eventObject' => string 'category' (length=8)
protected '_cacheTag' => string 'catalog_category' (length=16)
protected '_useFlatResource' => boolean true
private '_designAttributes' => 
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'custom_design' (length=13)
  1 => string 'custom_design_from' (length=18)
  2 => string 'custom_design_to' (length=16)
  3 => string 'page_layout' (length=11)
  4 => string 'custom_layout_update' (length=20)
  5 => string 'custom_apply_to_products' (length=24)
protected '_treeModel' => null
protected '_urlModel' => null
protected '_defaultValues' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
protected '_storeValuesFlags' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
protected '_lockedAttributes' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
protected '_isDeleteable' => boolean true
protected '_isReadonly' => boolean false
protected '_resourceName' => string 'catalog/category_flat' (length=21)
protected '_resource' => null
protected '_resourceCollectionName' => string   'catalog/category_flat_collection' (length=32)
protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
protected '_isObjectNew' => null
protected '_data' => 
array (size=37)
  'entity_id' => string '321' (length=3)
  'parent_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'created_at' => string '2015-02-02 14:50:55' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2015-02-23 12:33:52' (length=19)
  'path' => string '1/2/321' (length=7)
  'position' => string '2' (length=1)
  'level' => string '2' (length=1)
  'children_count' => string '23' (length=2)
  'store_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'all_children' => null
  'available_sort_by' => null
  'children' => null
  'custom_apply_to_products' => string '0' (length=1)
  'custom_design' => null
  'custom_design_from' => null
  'custom_design_to' => null
  'custom_layout_update' => null
  'custom_use_parent_settings' => string '0' (length=1)
  'default_sort_by' => null
  'description' => string '<div><img class="catimage" src="/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/default/images/columbarium-binnen.jpg" />

<div class="catdescription">

 <div class="cattitle"><h1>Urnen</h1></div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porta arcu vel dictum volutpat. Praesent molestie dolor at vehicula consectetur. Praesent dictum, ipsum ac porta dignissim, arcu purus mattis tellus, tempus semper ex ligula quis magna. per inceptos himenaeos.</div>

</div>

<p style="text-align: center;"><span>Uitv'... (length=771)
  'display_mode' => string 'PAGE' (length=4)
  'filter_price_range' => null
  'image' => null
  'include_in_menu' => string '1' (length=1)
  'is_active' => string '1' (length=1)
  'is_anchor' => string '0' (length=1)
  'landing_page' => string '15' (length=2)
  'meta_description' => string 'a' (length=1)
  'meta_keywords' => null
  'meta_title' => null
  'name' => string 'Urnen' (length=5)
  'page_layout' => null
  'path_in_store' => null
  'thumbnail' => null
  'url_key' => string 'urnen' (length=5)
  'url_path' => string 'urnen-17.html' (length=13)
  'path_ids' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '321' (length=3)
  protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
  protected '_origData' => 
array (size=36)
  'entity_id' => string '321' (length=3)
  'parent_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'created_at' => string '2015-02-02 14:50:55' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2015-02-23 12:33:52' (length=19)
  'path' => string '1/2/321' (length=7)
  'position' => string '2' (length=1)
  'level' => string '2' (length=1)
  'children_count' => string '23' (length=2)
  'store_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'all_children' => null
  'available_sort_by' => null
  'children' => null
  'custom_apply_to_products' => string '0' (length=1)
  'custom_design' => null
  'custom_design_from' => null
  'custom_design_to' => null
  'custom_layout_update' => null
  'custom_use_parent_settings' => string '0' (length=1)
  'default_sort_by' => null
  'description' => string '<div><img class="catimage" src="/skin/frontend/waterlee-boilerplate/default/images/columbarium-binnen.jpg" />

 <div class="catdescription">

 <div class="cattitle"><h1>Urnen</h1></div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porta arcu vel dictum volutpat. Praesent molestie dolor at vehicula consectetur. Praesent dictum, ipsum ac porta dignissim, arcu purus mattis tellus, tempus semper ex ligula quis magna. per inceptos himenaeos.</div>

 </div>

 <p style="text-align: center;"><span>Uitv'... (length=771)
  'display_mode' => string 'PAGE' (length=4)
  'filter_price_range' => null
  'image' => null
  'include_in_menu' => string '1' (length=1)
  'is_active' => string '1' (length=1)
  'is_anchor' => string '0' (length=1)
  'landing_page' => string '15' (length=2)
  'meta_description' => string 'a' (length=1)
  'meta_keywords' => null
  'meta_title' => null
  'name' => string 'Urnen' (length=5)
  'page_layout' => null
  'path_in_store' => null
  'thumbnail' => null
  'url_key' => string 'urnen' (length=5)
  'url_path' => string 'urnen-17.html' (length=13)
  protected '_idFieldName' => string 'entity_id' (length=9)
  protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
  protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
 protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Comment: Have a refresh cache before save attribute value ?

Comment: Done that multiple times, no luck sadly enough.

Comment: Having the same issue here, in my case it works locally but not our testing server

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this problem by emptying the cache, reindexing the website and adding the field again trough the link I've provided. Now I do have two fields with the wrong description but at least I've got it working.

Comment: I can hear the desperation in your voice